# How to check for python script requirements on windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, requirements

I have been developing a python script for a few days now, and wanted to send the final result to a friend of mine. Is there a way to get all software requirements to run my program?

The python part is relatively easy, as I can just look at my import list on my script. The problem is external software requirements.

For example, one of the python modules I'm using is Rasterio. I could not install this through conda or pip, until I installed Visual Studios C++ Community Version. I imagine there is some specific dll file that is being used. I can't really tell though.

I would really like to make a standalone setup.bat file, that installs all requirements and finally allows the user to simply run my program. I'm not 100% sure right now of those requirements though.

How can I get these?

Comment: which version of visual studio you've installed?

Comment: now, If you think that some c++ DLL is being used by your application then you've to attach VC++ Redistributable with your application. you can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: Have you tried packaging your program with something like [`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Is already answered with a pip package
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670995/retrieving-the-requirements-of-a-python-single-script/60890711#60890711

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly check your application dependencies using **Dependency Walker** get it from [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Comment: yes... you've to build your project. then try installing on other PC. and check dependencies.