# Retrieving the requirements of a Python single script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I would like to know how to extract the requirements from a single python script. I tried the following way, at the beginning of my file, immediately after the imports:

```
try:
    from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError:  # pip < 10.0
    from pip.operations import freeze

x = freeze.freeze()
for p in x:
    print(p)
```

The piece of code above, however, gives me back all the Python frameworks installed locally. I would like to extract **only** the necessary requirements for the script, in order to be able to deploying the final application. 
I hope I was clear.

Comment: There is no way for pip to know this. The only way to know what the requirements for a module are is for someone to document them.

Comment: And additionally, this sounds a bit like an XY problem. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Create a virtual environment, install only the necessary requirements for the script, and then pip freeze will give you only what you need.

Comment: @grooveplex In a nutshell, I would like to extract the requirements of a python file, but not all the libraries installed locally!! Which the piece of code mentioned above gives me back ...

Comment: @TGO Quite right! I had not thought about it... This could be a good idea, thank you!

Comment: The developer is responsible for the installed packages and a clean `requirements.txt`. At work we maintain the packages in the `requirements.txt` by hand, because a `pip freeze` adds all dependencies and sub-dependencies to the list which is sometimes confusing. Nevertheless you can checkout [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/modulefinder.html) which is a stdlib library to inspect the loaded modules.

Comment: @DariusMorawiec another good and pythonic solution! Thanks, I really like this!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**pipreqs is simple to use**

install:

`pip install pipreqs`

in linux in the same folder of your script
use:

`pipreqs .`

then the requirements.txt file is created

pip home page:

https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/

Comment: Haven't tried it, but seems like a better solution than the currently accepted one.

Comment: Strange tool. It gives me `torch_geometric==2.2.0` while the version I use is 2.0.4

Comment: My recommendation now is to use poetry for install and manage packages

Answer (score 5):

***You can do this easily with 'modulefinder' python module.***

*I think you want to print all the modules required by a script. 
So, you can refer to*

http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-find-out-what-modules-a-python-script-requires/

*or for your ease the code is here:*

---

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
f = ModuleFinder()
# Run the main script
f.run_script('run.py')
# Get names of all the imported modules
names = list(f.modules.keys())
# Get a sorted list of the root modules imported
basemods = sorted(set([name.split('.')[0] for name in names]))
# Print it nicely
print ("\n".join(basemods))
```

---

Comment: I hope, I helped you.

Comment: Excellent solution! If there was also the way to retrieve versioning, we could also generate the `requirements.txt` file. But for what I have to do, it's exhaustive to know the name of the frameworks! ;) So thank you so much!

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you.

Comment: Am I wrong to think this would only give you the imported modules, but not the projects that need to be _pip-installed_?

Comment: no it includes all types of modules used by a python script

Comment: I didn't file it useful. For a simple script it gives me tons of stuff, for some other scripts it just fails with an exception inside.